# Normal behaviour for API performance?

Tags: java, spring, performance, rest

I'm currently testing API performance and finding that the first few requests are always very slow. 1000ms to 3000ms for the same request. When running it in jMeter it eventually consistently responds around 300ms. The server is located halfway across the world if that makes a difference.

It's a REST api coded in Java using Spring
JSON response.
GET Request
Has an Authorization and accept/json header

I've also noticed that there unsuccessful responses are on average slower than the successful ones. Could this be related to different performance for different status codes? Or more likely a code issue?

Looking at my logs, all transactions complete in the server within 1 ms.

Comment: You say the server answers fast, so the times you see are due to the network. You may be observing some sort of caching effects if later requests are faster. For other patterns you believe to see in the data check if they are statistically relevant or just random fluctuations.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of possibilities that may be affecting your performance and metrics.

1. Persistent connections, and connection pooling / caching (assuming you have this enabled) may speed up subsequent queries due to not requiring the round trip connection setup (assuming TCP), and / or SSL handshake (assuming HTTPS or SSH).
2. The order of magnitude of the performance difference does suggest the possibility of more than network delays, which raises the question: are you really sure that all of the server requests complete within 1ms (including the first few requests)?  From when to when are you actually timing (from entry into the rest layer, or from the http server log or..)?
3. If the first few requests that are slow also happen to be the first requests to the server since server startup then there is perhaps some additional object instantiation / data loading occurring which delays the ability of the server to respond.
4. It should be unlikely, but there could be caching occurring somewhere on the network if there are any proxies involved.  This could be easily determined by comparing the number of requests recorded by the server to the number of requests actually issued.

Comment: I also don't think that actual response is cached, but for example DNS lookup data could be cached.

Comment: Thanks! To answer the questions: 1. Will look into this further. Likely culprit. 2. Yes quite sure - measurement is total processing time within the application. Not from the http server log. 3. Slow every time, not just after startup. 4. No proxies.

Comment: @Henry DNS lookup should only take 100ms max. Would not be responsible for 1000ms delay surely?